# When multiple developers use cPanel, can they get individual passwords that prevent them from uploading into each other's directories?

Tags: cpanel, directory, protection, password

I have multiple developers working on my cPanel account simultaneously. I want to assign them individual directories to work.  I would need to be able to secure other directories from the  developers not working on it.

I want the website user to be able to access the pages via their web browsers and not be asked credentials.

Comment: Do the developers have to use cPanel? Can they just use FTP to get at their directories?

Comment: ya they can use that. But i was thinking if there can be a way to do that in cpanel also.

Comment: I don't see why any developer would want to use cpanel over shell/sftp. It's easier to just create a separate shell/sftp account for each dev and limit them to their own directory. If you can create separate cpanel users, that would also work, but unless you have a webhosting reseller account, I don't think that's likely.

Answer (score 1):

cPanel is not meant for this purpose.

[paulmorriss](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/1643/paulmorriss) says:

> Do the developers have to use cPanel? Can they just use FTP to get at their directories?

[Lèse majesté](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/1757/lese-majeste) says:

> I don't see why any developer would want to use cpanel over shell/sftp. It's easier to just create a separate shell/sftp account for each dev and limit them to their own directory. If you can create separate cpanel users, that would also work, but unless you have a webhosting reseller account, I don't think that's likely.